# How to stop SED from un-escaping the output?

Tags: json, bash, sed

There's a million sed-related questions, but I couldn't find this specific case. I will happily stand corrected if it turns out I'm a bad googler.

I have a file with special characters and newline in it Let's call it query.kql:

```
Metrics
| where $__timeFilter(TimeGenerated)
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK"
| order by TimeGenerated asc
```

I also have a json file. It's called data.json:

```json
{
"analytics": {
            "query": "{{query.kql}}",
            "resource": "$GlobalDataSource",
            "resultFormat": "time_series"
          }
}
```

What I want to do it insert the contents of query.kql into the {{query.kql}} placeholder in data.json, in escaped form (newline->\n, "->", etc)

This gives me the contents of query.kql in the desired format (works):

```sh
q=$(sed -e "N;s/\n/\\\n/" -e 's|["]|\\"|g' query.kql)
#q: AzureMetrics\n| where $__timeFilter(TimeGenerated) | where ResourceProvider == \"MICROSOFT.NETWORK\"\n| order by TimeGenerated asc
```

What I've tried:

```sh
# This does not work, because sed chokes on the result of the shell substitution:
sed -e "s/{{query.kql}}/$q/g" data.json
# Output: sed: -e expression #1, char 79: unterminated `s' command
```

```sh
# This works, but the output is wrong:
sed -e "s/{{query.kql}}/`echo $q`/g" data.json

# Output is unescaped and makes the json structure invalid:
"analytics": {
            "query": "AzureMetrics
| where $__timeFilter(TimeGenerated) | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK"
| order by TimeGenerated asc",
            "resource": "$GlobalDataSource",
            "resultFormat": "time_series"
          },
```

What I would like to have as output, is the exact contents of q inserted:

```json
{
"analytics": {
            "query": "AzureMetrics\n| where $__timeFilter(TimeGenerated) | where ResourceProvider == \"MICROSOFT.NETWORK\"\n| order by TimeGenerated asc",
            "resource": "$GlobalDataSource",
            "resultFormat": "time_series"
          }
}
```

How can I get sed to maintain the original contents of $q in the output?
I'm also open to suggestions using awk, perl or anything also commonly available from a bash script.

**Update**

Turns out my main issue was in reading the content of the file into the $q variable in a properly escaped way. If that is done right, there is also no need to use `echo $q` in the second *sed* command.
I ended up with this working just right:

```sh
# The first part escapes quotes and backslashes, the second part replaces the newlines by \n
query=$( sed -z 's#["\]#\\\\\\&#g;s/\n/\\\\n/g' query.kql)

# I had to do some playing around before I found a suitable separator char, but turns out ~ does the trick in this specific case.
sed -i -e "s~{{query.kql}}~$query~g" $data.json
```

Comment: Do you really need to replace the newlines with `\n`?

Comment: ,1 Just use double quotes: `q="$(sed ...)"`

Comment: .2 You don't nedd `\`echo $q\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are almost there. I think if you try and double escape the string you would get what you want. Try the following:

```bash
q=$(cat query.kql | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\\\n/g' -e 's#["]#\\\\"#g')
sed -e "s/{{query.kql}}/$q/g" data.json
```

Here is my output:

```
{
"analytics": {
            "query": "Metrics\n| where $__timeFilter(TimeGenerated)\n| where ResourceProvider == \"MICROSOFT.NETWORK\"\n| order by TimeGenerated asc",
            "resource": "$GlobalDataSource",
            "resultFormat": "time_series"
          }
}
```

**Edit:** By the way, you should also escape the backslashes '\' before escaping anything else. Otherwise you might end up interpreting original backslashes as escaping in the end result. `sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g'` right before all other substitutions should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For dealing with JSON in the shell you should use `jq`:

```sh
jq --arg kql "$(< query.kql)" '.analytics.query = $kql' data.json
```

```json
{
  "analytics": {
    "query": "Metrics\n| where $__timeFilter(TimeGenerated)\n| where ResourceProvider == \"MICROSOFT.NETWORK\"\n| order by TimeGenerated asc",
    "resource": "$GlobalDataSource",
    "resultFormat": "time_series"
  }
}
```

---

##### Update

As OP doesn't know the JSON structure in advance, then using a language that has a JSON encoder in its core library would be best.

- with ruby; replace all occurrences of `{{query.kql}}`:

```sh
ruby -rjson -pe 'BEGIN {kql = File.read("query.kql").to_json[1..-2]}; gsub("{{query.kql}}", kql)' < data.json
```

- with `jq`; update all keys whose value is `"{{query.kql}}"`:

```sh
jq --arg kql "$(< query.kql)" '.. |= if (. == "{{query.kql}}") then . =  $kql else . end' data.json
```

Comment: Thanks, will keep that in mind! Not the best fit in this case since the script is unaware of the exact json structure at replace time.

Comment: Oh! I updated my answer to reflect that point ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ q=$(sed '2s/|/\\\\n&/;s/"/\\\\&/g;4s/|/\\\\n&/' query.kql)
$ sed "s/{{query.kql}}/`echo $q`/" data.json
{
"analytics": {
            "query": "AzureMetrics \n| where (TimeGenerated) | where ResourceProvider == \"MICROSOFT.NETWORK\" \n| order by TimeGenerated asc",
            "resource": "",
            "resultFormat": "time_series"
          }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is point of using `echo` in the last RHS, looks like `$q` should suffice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Indeed. However, OP mentions that he/she has tried that and it does not work for him/her. I have used a solution that seems works for them.

Comment: When the input string is properly escaped, echo is no longer needed. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{{\([^}]*\)}}/{
      s//\n\1\n/
      h
      s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/\1/
      s/.*/cat "&"/e
      s/\n/\\n/g
      s/"/\\"/g
      H
      g
      s/\n.*\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/
      s/^/\n/
      D}' file
```

Identify the line containing the file to be inserted i.e. the string between `{{` and `}}`.

Delimit the file name by newlines.

Make a copy of the line.

Remove everything but the file name.

Replace the file name by its contents.

Escape newlines and double quotes.

Append the string of amended file contents to the original line.

Replace the file name by its amended contents.

Repeat until failure.

Comment: is it POSIX `sed`?

Comment: @Fravadona No it uses the `e` flag in the substitution command which evaluates the RHS i.e. `cat file`.